# Detection of noise and signal components with deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, pytorch

There are thousands of datasets from the signal in the bellow image. With these datasets and machine learning, I want to first detect the jumping points (blue in the image) which are noises, and after removing these noises, find three parts of the signal including a constant value (red), a sinusoidal value (green) and a triangular value (orange). and report the length of the time interval and the maximum value and the time of the maximum value of each. Please guide me which algorithm and deep learning method should I use?
[image]